# ArrayFormula for if Date is greater than Value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a formula which pulls data from a separate sheet and selects only rows which fulfill a date comparison.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
=ArrayFormula(if('Complete Staff List'!E2:E < Date(2017;1;1), 'Complete Staff list'!B:C))
```

So in theory, it should pull all employees who started before 2017.

I understand how ArrayFormula works, but I can't manage to get the 'if' operation to work with it.

Comment: Does `=ArrayFormula(if('Complete Staff List'!E2:E < Date(2017;1;1), 'Complete Staff list'!B2:C))` do it for you? Comparative ranges must be the same size.

Comment: It does nothing, it only results in anerror. I don't expect it to work either, because I know something is wrong. I'm not very experienced with spreadsheet formulas. I've looked around and read similar posts, but none of them could help me in this specific scenario.

Comment: Well, for reference, I'm able to run =ArrayFormula('Complete Staff List'!D2:D) which returns the whole column starting at D2. I don't know if it works in Excel

Comment: What I want the 'IF' operation to do, is to compare the E cell on the same row as pulled from ArrayFormula

Comment: Use Query instead of the array formula.

Comment: I looked at the query formula and it seems to suit my need. However, I'm unable to pull data from a separate sheet. Could you give me an example of look?

Comment: This is what I've tried: =QUERY(Importrange("DataSheet!B:C"), "select * where Col5 < date '2017-01-01'")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you want to use `query`, not `arrayformula`.

In an unused cell with room for results,

```
=query(B2:E,"select B,C,E where E < date'2017-01-01'")
```

[image]

Dates as criteria in `query` are particular. See the section on dates in [Google sheets query functuion](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BV94ZVI1b1AkM0xOx503mfo01Yj9CVtdFXdQZzelGNk/edit#heading=h.rv76rm16szmc) and examples at [More query function examples](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dwHYPnQTMtH7qRkl1E-O7fYEevrr15x8qfiwktmrVgM/edit#gid=1484848351). From a separate sheet, use a named range to make life easy.

Comment: Okay, now I see what Query does. And that's not what I'm after. I have a list of names and dates in one sheet. And I want to pull all names from that list, which corresponding date matches a criteria, into another sheet.

Comment: You're right, I was too quick to discard Query. It is what I'm after. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
    =ArrayFormula(if('Complete Staff List'!E:E < Date(2017;1;1), 'Complete Staff list'!B:B))
```

Comment: To test the formula, I tried this too: =ArrayFormula(if(1 < 2, 'Complete Staff list'!B:C)) that neither works. Are you using Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: i use Ms Excel 2013